# The simplest way to signal any WaitHandle after specified time

Tags: c#, timeout, signals, .net-5, waithandle

I'm looking for any simple way to have any waitable object to be signaled after specified time.
Now I'm using something like:

```
int delayMs = 500; // milliseconds
AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new(false);
using Task autoSignalTask = Task.Run(() => 
{
    Thread.Sleep(delayMs);
    resetEvent.Set();
});
```

but it seems to be too complicated ;)

Is there something simpler, like below?

```
int delayMs = 500; // milliseconds
SomeWaitableObject waitableObject = new();
waitableObject.SignalAfter(delayMs);
```

Comment: Put your code into an extension method and use that extension method.

Comment: I tought about this, but I'm worried about the task lifetime... It shouldn't be disposed inside this extension method.

Comment: It will not get disposed. You should also rethink using `Task.Delay()` to save performance

Comment: BTW `CancellationTokenSource` and its token is also an option ;o)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your initial sample, it would look like

```cs
int delayMs = 500; // milliseconds
AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new(false);
// await Task.Delay(delayMs); // the author need to do it sync
Thread.Sleep(delayMs);
resetEvent.Set();
```

Comment: Yes, but using 'await' implies that the method needs to be 'async' - what is not expected.

Comment: Well, I am totally missing your point now.
Thread.Sleep(delayMs) would do the desired behavior.
I have updated the answer.